How to calculate throughput using promql in grafana?
I have pushed my application metrices to prometheus using micrometer. I'm trying to calculate throughput of an api using the below query:
sum(rate(http_client_requests_seconds_count{application_id="xyz", cf_application_name="app_name"}[60m]))

As I'm new to Promql, I'm trying to fetch number of requests hit by an api per second. Is this query looks good for throughput calcualtion ? or do I need to modify the query ?
